# What is the rationale of banning proof-of-work instead of highly taxing it?

Tags: taxes, energy-policy, cryptocurrency

According to [CoinDesk](https://www.coindesk.com/policy/2022/01/19/eu-markets-regulator-calls-for-ban-on-proof-of-work-crypto-mining-report/), the vice-chair of the European Securities and Markets Authority (ESMA) suggested that cryptocurrency mining based on proof-of-work should be banned:

> Proof-of-work crypto mining should be banned in the European Union (EU), according to the vice chair of the European Securities and Markets Authority (ESMA).

The main reason for doing so is the relatively high energy consumption this protocol involves while the less energy-intensive proof-of-stake could be used instead.

I am wondering why banning is suggested instead of heavily taxation (e.g. have a very high tax for energy consumption above a certain threshold except for designated industries).

Comment: The original source is behind a paywall, is the suggestion banning just mining, or also banning transactions involving PoW cryptos?

Comment: @Caleth Not really sure, but the article does not mention banning the transactions anywhere.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133500/discussion-on-question-by-alexei-what-is-the-rationale-of-banning-proof-of-work).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Taxation is already complicated enough, and complicated legal codes create unintentional consequences and loopholes.

"Have a very high tax for energy consumption above a certain threshold except for designated industries" raises the question of what industries are those "designated industries". When there is a new kind of industry which is actually really beneficial for the political goals of the EU but isn't on the exemption list yet, then it might not be economically feasible until the EU updates that list. This could become a blocker for technological innovation. And how exactly do you define those industries? A definition which is too broad might enable cryptocurrency miners to find loopholes which allow them to masquerade as another industry. "We use the heat from our 100 server racks to pre-warm this tiny smelting furnace, so we are actually a steel mill which just does some cryptocurrency mining on the side".

And then there is the question if taxation really stops cryptocurrency mining. One theory about crypto-economics is that cryptocurrency is valuable *because* it is expensive to mine. When someone wants cryptocurrency, then they can choose between buying it or mining it themselves. A rational person will do whatever is less expensive. But when everyone decides to buy, then demand increases, which means the price increases. Until it reaches the mining price, and mining becomes again the preferred form of acquiring cryptocurrency. Which means that the prices for cryptocurrency will regress to the cost it takes to mine new cryptocurrency. So making mining more expensive means that the prices for cryptocurrency will just increase accordingly making mining profitable again.

Comment: It's even worse than the steel mill example.  It seems possible for people to argue its not even an industry at all.  I know of one family who heats their house with a few dozen crypto miners in the floor.  "It's not a business, it's our furnace.  You're really gonna tax us for being warm?"

Comment: It's not that much of a bad faith argument, heating their house with a crypto miner is as efficient as with an electric heater (albeit much less than with a heat pump). But do they turn it off in summer ?

Comment: @Ryan_L The idea of taxing low-efficiency consumers is not unheard of.

Comment: @fraxinus: All of the electrical energy that goes into the computer is eventually converted to waste heat, so the computer has exactly the same efficiency (100%) as a regular electric space heater. You could tax those too, on account of them being much less efficient than heat pumps and (depending on how electricity is generated) possibly more carbon-intensive than a natural gas furnace, but it doesn't make a whole lot of economic sense to allow electric space heaters but not mining.

Comment: @Kevin It makes sense. Most people already have a strong incentive to not use electric space heaters as their primary heat source: they're a wildly expensive form of heating. At an average European household electricity rate of ~€0.22/kWh, a single 1500W space heater, wildly insufficient on its own to heat a whole home, would cost €240 to run 24/7, while a heat pump consuming the same amount of electricity may output 5X the heat or more as the space heater.

Comment: Crypto mining risks inverting that natural incentive since the mining pays for the electricity costs. Governments don't want people to use crypto mining to heat their homes, since that consumes far more energy than essentially any other heat source, so it makes sense they'd want policies to discourage that behavior. But there's no need for new policies to discourage the use of electric space heaters, since anyone capable of reading an electric bill is already discouraged from using them unnecessarily.

Comment: @Philipp the first part of your argument could be used for banning mining altogether. banning things also has unintended consequences and could stifle innovation

Comment: @ZachLipton, you didn't mention how long you'd need to run a space heater in order to pay €240, but by your math it looks like about a month. Might want to edit that in.

Comment: @Ryan_L Do those acquaintances also heat their house in summer the same way?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I assume they just cook lol.

Comment: Another issue with 'tax above a threshold' is that it's generally trivial to create a new company, which can break up the usage into an unlimited set of discrete groups none of which would individually exceed the threshold. If they were producing physical products, then it's harder to split up production but since it's all digital then it's pretty simple.

Comment: @ZachLipton True, but this could become interesting and complicated unless one simultaneously tries to tax space heaters for being inefficient.

Comment: @Ryan_L because, if they continue their mining in summer **and** run AC then they probably 2x the problem:  data centers don't pursue CPU/system efficiency *just* to forego the extra cost of powering the gear, they also pursue it because an extra 1W in system power use typically results in *n* extra watts of cooling power requirements where *n* is [possibly larger than 1](https://dataspan.com/blog/data-center-cooling-costs/).  In other words, if they run AC and mining in the summer, your friends claims are full of it.

Comment: @Ryan_L Crypto mining rigs are optimized for lowering energy consumption, so if by "crypto mining", you mean a rigs specifically designed for that, they paid much more for their "heater" than a normal one costs. Also, the crypto income subsidizes the heating, which from an economic point of view means that they are paying less than the "true" cost to society of the heating, which likely causes them to consume more than the socially optimal (e.g. maybe they would be fine with their house being70 degrees F, but with the crypto subsidy they heat it to 72).

Comment: @DavidJacobsen: That's largely solvable by binding the taxation to the power grid connection point (meter) and requiring the tax to be associated with a party with physical connection to that place. For off-grid (miners running their own power plant) operations, then, the scale needed to make it practical should take care of itself. In a discussion a couple months ago about taxation, myself and some others involved worked out a rough sketch for how businesses with a legitimate need for large amounts of computing energy (i.e. cloud providers)...

Comment: ...would need to link it to the customer's tax quota to avoid the gigantic taxation (meaning customers who want ridiculous amounts of anonymous compute time would end up paying their host's tax in lieu of identifying themselves for tax purposes).

Comment: These complexities themselves, however, highlight some of why a ban might be preferable to trying to work out a good taxation system. But they also highlight how hard a ban fundamentally is - due to "the cloud" (high volume rented computing) a ban can't really be enforced without destroying privacy of rented computation.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Cryptocurrencies have the useful (for this) characteristic that there is a verifiable public ledger that records mining activity. I'd expect that enforcement would focus on this, and the offramps that are used to convert to national currencies, rather than cloud computing providers. I'm also under the impression that almost no mining happens on any general purpose cloud computing providers, since most mining relies on specialised hardware, and even the mining that can be done on general purpose hardware is not profitable without vertical integration.

Comment: The price thing is not quite like that: the total income from mining is a fixed amount (relative to miners) and people are competing for their share of the pie. If mining becomes 5x as expensive, people do 1/5 as much mining and get the same number of bitcoins

Comment: @James_pic How will you determine whether the person exchanging bitcoins for dollars is the same person who originally mined the bitcoins?

Comment: @James_pic: My point is that, if dedicated mining rigs were effectively banned, general-purpose cloud computing infrastructure (especially now that ones with gpus are a thing) would likely become the dominant form of mining. Also there are PoW schemes designed not to scale better on gpus or asics so that general purpose computing is a reasonable choice of mining hardware, which might rise to prominence under such a scenario.

Answer (score 43):

It's fundamentally a different message: "This is an economic activity that is unacceptable" vs "This is an economic activity that we want a larger cut from".

Comment: Or "this is an activity we disagree with, but can't feasibly ban", like taxes on cigarettes or fossil fuel consumption.

Comment: Except many democracies are gradually banning cigarettes and fossil fuels, certainly in some areas, with plans to eliminate smoking and proposed bans on new ICE cars, gas heating, fossil fuel exploration, etc.

Comment: @nick012000 Part of that is because those are existing products and fossil fuels still have value where proof-of-work is a new product and people question the value it provides.

Comment: @StuartF "This is an activity we disagree with, and can only feasibly ban if we get enough public support to do so".

Comment: @JoeW: The other part is that a gradually-increasing Pigouvian tax, which follows a predictable trajectory, is much less economically disruptive than a sudden ban after (in most cases) years of political dilly-dallying. If you know the tax rate 10 years from now, you can amortize that and plan for it.

Comment: @StuartF democraties will never ban cigarettes. It generates too much income.

Comment: Proof-of-work isn't really a new product, Bitcoin has been around for 13 years now, and it was used as far back as 1993 to rate-limit email spammers.

Comment: @kaya3 13 years is a short time in legislation

Comment: @Itération122442 [tell that to New Zealand](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-59589775)

Comment: @StuartF, yeah, they're banning cigarettes and fossil fuels _now_, after increasingly taxing and otherwise discouraging them (e.g. with the mandatory warnings and icky pictures on cigarette packs).

Comment: @kaya3 13 years is nothing compared to fossil fuels, cigarettes and other products. Not to mention it does take time to fully understand and regulate new products as needed.

Comment: @AakashM really surprising, actually, and they will probably reverse it if they ever want to legalize cannabis

Answer (score 20):

### Enforcement

It's much simpler to determine whether a mining activity is occurring at all or that certain equipment exists (and can be seized) than to measure its quantity in a way that's hard to cheat. Highly taxing it would require either extensive and expensive monitoring, or accepting that it will be circumvented because the equipment and the activity itself would be permitted.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this argument is actually empirically true. When something is taxed and regulated, most people will follow the law and openly disclose their activities. When something is prohibited, a black market that is entirely designed around hiding the activity entirely from officials tends to arise, that can make enforcement activity more difficult.

Comment: *"When something is taxed and regulated, most people will follow the law and openly disclose their activities."* That may be true, but the vast proportion of mining (in terms of energy use) is done by very few people, and those are people who have invested heavily in crypto mining equipment which won't be profitable if they pay a heavy tax while also competing against other miners who don't have to (or who evade it). So we're talking about a relatively small number of people with strong incentives to evade such a tax.

Comment: @ohwilleke There are two main reasons for people to follow a law, say like the speed limit. 1) they genuinely see the law as useful and don't want to speed for their own safety. 2) They are afraid of the punishment if caught ie., expensive tickets. A large population will disregard the law if there is no punishment for breaking it. So "most people will follow the law and openly disclose their activities" is not something I'd agree on. Yes regulated instead of prohibition is better for the government to keep an eye on instead of driving it underground.

Answer (score 4):

**Ease of Subversion**

Governments throughout history have earned a tidy profit through currency debasement.  In the modern era of fiat currencies this has been pushed to ludicrous levels.  Depending on which numbers you go with, for example, the US Dollar has been reduced in value by as much as 98% since 1900, with the surplus cash going directly to the government and its cronies.

Cryptocurrency is a threat to this major cash cow because it is community controlled, so it is difficult for one actor to subvert it to their own purposes.

Proof of work has no cap on its difficulty.  To subvert a network would require ongoing investment in computing power and the electricity to run it.  This is not only expensive, it is expensive unpredictably and continuously.  Furthermore, it would be relatively easy for someone to notice that a government was doing it due to the space and power requirements for the hardware.

Proof of stake on the other hand, once you've purchased 51% of the tokens, that's it, the network is yours forever, and there's nothing anyone can do about it other than a hard fork.  This is still expensive, but it's an easily calculable, one-time expense.  Furthermore, it doesn't take a big pile of hardware and power usage that's hard to hide.  So obviously proof of stake is preferable for large actors with plans to subvert and exploit a cryptocurrency for their own purposes.

Merely taxing proof of work schemes won't guarantee their extinction, even if it weren't an easy tax to evade.  Currency which cannot easily be debased by a third party is, economically, an extremely valuable thing.  Applying a tax is likely to simply drive up the price of the tokens to compensate.  A total ban with harsh penalties for anyone caught using such systems has a much higher likelihood of success.

Comment: I am entertained by the war between the up and down votes. Inflation has always been a jealously guarded source of government income.  Juan de Mariana, a contemporary of Cervantes, wrote a book saying it was morally permissible to kill the king and they ignored him. But writing one saying that currency debasement was theft got him sentenced to death and he had to flee the country. And that is hardly an isolated example.

Comment: Juan de Mariana may not be an isolated example, but he's also not a recent example, or one that relates to proof-of-work cryptocurrencies. Do you have any examples that demonstrate that current politicians regard proof-of-work cryptocurrencies as a threat to their power of debasement or subversion (as opposed to threats to more day-to-day concerns, such as CO2 targets, energy security, money laundering, drugs, fraud, or tax evasion)?

Comment: @James_pic  For crypto specifically?  No.  Government hasn't been paying attention to it for long enough for much specific evidence of the actual thought process to ooze out between the cracks.  Still though, the efforts to get government currency production and interest rate setting audited always meet with phenomenal resistance for no specific reason... And talk of constant inflation not being good in the long-run is always shouted down.  Meanwhile, the energy/CO2 cost is the only one of those concerns where the algorithm matters, and that is self-balancing with the cost of electricity.